# How to listen to thread exit event if thread is from another process?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible in .NET to fire method when thread exits if only thread id is given?

```
   var windowThreadId = User32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, out processId);
```

Is it possible to do it like this? :

```
 var process = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId);
 process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Exited.");
 };
```

Comment: Since that you mentioned Process, do you want the exited event to be fired for thread exits within the process, or for other processes as well ?

Comment: What about [`GetExitCodeThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190(v=vs.85).aspx)? I don't know whether it is part of `User32`, but it is definitely part of the windows API

Answer (score 0):

So these days there is [this UnmanagedThreadUtils library](https://github.com/ptupitsyn/UnmanagedThreadUtils) that allows you to do exactly what you're looking to achieve:

(Official) Example:

```cs
// Use static field to make sure that delegate is alive.
private static readonly UnmanagedThread.ThreadExitCallback ThreadExitCallbackDelegate = OnThreadExit;

public static void Main()
{
    var threadExitCallbackDelegatePtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(ThreadExitCallbackDelegate);
    var callbackId = UnmanagedThread.SetThreadExitCallback(threadExitCallbackDelegatePtr);

    for (var i = 1; i <= ThreadCount; i++)
    {
        var threadLocalVal = i;

        var thread = new Thread(_ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Managed thread #{threadLocalVal} started.");
            UnmanagedThread.EnableCurrentThreadExitEvent(callbackId, new IntPtr(threadLocalVal));
        });

        thread.Start();
    }

    UnmanagedThread.RemoveThreadExitCallback(callbackId);
}

private static void OnThreadExit(IntPtr data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Unmanaged thread #{data.ToInt64()} is exiting.");
}
```